# Regex: Search in regex for the same value

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this string :

```
const test = `
/**
 * @test
 * {
 * }
 * @example
 * {
 *    "name": "Error",
 * }
 * @test
 * {
 * }
 * @example
 * {
 *    "name": "Success",
 * }
 */
`;
```

And i would like to return all the `@example` found in the string.
Here is my code :

```
const regexExample = /@example[\s\S]*?(?=@test|$)/g;
let m;
do {
  m = regexExample.exec(test)
  if (m) {
    console.log(m[0]);
    return m[0];
  }
} while (m);
```

The output i get is :

```
@example
 * {
 *    "name": "Error",
 * }
 *
```

How can i search for all the `@example`, and if an `@` is found to verify if it's equivelant to `@example`

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı i'm doing the same thing but it's not working

Comment: @DoğancanArabacı i'm working with a loop as well

Comment: @brxnzaz write the expected result

Comment: Why are you `return`ing in the loop?. Remove it and this should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is good, just use it with [String.prototype.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) to get all matches in one go:

```js
const test = `
/**
 * @test
 * {
 * }
 * @example
 * {
 *    "name": "Error",
 * }
 * @test
 * {
 * }
 * @example
 * {
 *    "name": "Success",
 * }
 */
`;

const matches = test.match(/@example[\s\S]*?(?=@test|$)/g);

matches.forEach(m => console.log(m));
```